# AWS Cloudformation Master Template creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a master template which calls other templates.My first template is VPC and subnet creation and second one is creating bastion host. Problem i am facing is i am not able to ref. the created VPC in my second template due to which its failing. My master template looks like below:-

```
Description: >

    This template deploys the full agyle time stack as follows, which consists of:

    A VPC with with public and private subnets spread across two Availabilty Zones.
    It deploys an Internet Gateway and a pair of NAT Gateways, with the relevant routes in each of the subnets.

    It then deploys the API ECS cluster distributed across multiple Availability Zones.

    Finally, it deploys the API ECS services deployed as containers within the ECS repository
Parameters:
    S3TemplateKeyPrefix:
        Description: >
            An S3 key prefix which will be used to resolve referenced templates
        Type: String

Resources:

    VPC:
        Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
        Properties:
            TemplateURL: !Sub ${S3TemplateKeyPrefix}/infrastructure/vpc.yaml

    Bastion:
        Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
        Properties:
            TemplateURL: !Sub ${S3TemplateKeyPrefix}/infrastructure/bastion.yaml
            Parameters: 
                EnvironmentName: !Ref AWS::StackName
                VPC: !GetAtt VPC.Outputs.VPC
```

Can someone help me here do i have to modify VPC and Bastion host template to reference my VPC in bastion template.

Comment: Can you post some more info like the error message and how you are trying to reference the VPC parameter in the `Bastion` template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue with modifying the child templates with Export and Import Function and calling it in master template. below is what I used:-

Outputs:

```
PubPrivateVPC: 
    Description: A reference to the created VPC
    Value: !Ref PubPrivateVPC
    Export:
      Name: VPC-PROD
```

and import

Parameter:-
  NetworkStackName:
    Description: >-
      Name of an active CloudFormation stack that contains the networking
      resources, such as the subnet and security group, that will be used in
      this stack.
    Type: String
    MinLength: 1
    MaxLength: 255
    AllowedPattern: '^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$'
    Default: VPC-PROD

and in resources called like below:-
      VpcId: !ImportValue VPC-PROD

No i am able to call child templates in master successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your master template, I believe it fails because CFN starts creating both of them in parallel, whereas `Bastion` needs to be created after your `VPC` resource. Just add the `DependsOn: VPC` for your `Bastion` resource to have it created only after your `VPC` has been created.

```
Bastion:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  DependsOn: VPCStack
  Properties:
```

Here's a working example from AWS [saas-identity-cognito-master.template](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/saas-identity-cognito/blob/master/templates/saas-identity-cognito-master.template).

Comment: I am getting error while calling my bastion template                                
  Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:676765101344:stack/VPC-Bastion-1C040J19XQ9ID/68bdb020-38c7-11e9-9ecb-0e33f445a498 was not successfully created: No export named VPC-VPCID found .. I am calling the import value in bastion template like  :-
      VpcId: !ImportValue 
        'Fn::Sub': '${NetworkStackName}-VPCID'  whereas in output section of VPC template i am exporting value like
        Value: !Ref PubPrivateVPC
        Export:
          Name: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-VPCID'

Comment: Looks like a mismatch between export & import names. How does the export name look like? You can view it CFN console. Also, from your above template, it looks like you are passing the `VPC id` to your bastion template. In that case you do not need to import it. Add it as another variable in `Parameters` section.